# Using dictionary mapping to call functions from Keyboard Input

Tags: python

I have several pre-defined functions in a dictionary:

```
dict = {
   'test1':test1(),
    'test2':test2(), 
    'test3':test3()
}
```

At this point I already have a question: after creating the dictionary these functions run automatically - why is that and how can I avoid it?

Ultimately, my goal is to type in e.g. "test2" and get the function executed (just the one in a controlled manner, not everything at once like above). First I wanted to use `eval`, but everyone advised against it, which I understand now. But what is the alternative? I tried

```
def select_function():
    try:
        return dict[input("Type in function ")]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid input!')
select_function()
```

as well as just

```
dict.get(input("Type in function "), 'Invalid input!')
```

But both return an **empty line** if I type in the correct function. If I type in a wrong one I get my error message, therefore my command should work in general. I also know my functions work because, as I said, they get executed after I create the dictionary and they only print a greeting (a different one for each function for testing).

Did I do something wrong? Is there some other way to call functions without `eval()`?Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you put `()` after a function name, you are calling it. If you don't want to call it, don't put `()` after the name.

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought otherwise Python doesn't see it as a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like

```
dict = {
   'test1':test1,
    'test2':test2, 
    'test3':test3
}
```

Then

```
return dict[input("Type in function")]
```

If you want to call that function, Just

```
return dict[input("Type in function")]()
```